# Not Found error when charging Square API

Tags: square, square-connect

The Square REST API docs state that I should get a list of my locations and then use a returned location code when I call the transactions endpoint (to charge a credit card). I am doing exactly this but the returned error says that the merchant has no location with the supplied ID.

I have tried this with and without the location_id in the JSON sent to the transactions endpoint, since it is a path variable. Same result. I have also seen on Square's API FAQ that the usual cause of a 404 not found is the card nonce being created wrong, but this response clearly says the location ID is not valid.

I have tested this with Postman and JSON and I can see that the location code is correct. Here are my calls and the responses:

This is a GET request:

```
https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations
```

And here is the response:

```
{
"locations": [
{
  "id": "FPVPFZ4DXXXXX",
  "name": "MyCompany",
  "address": {
    "address_line_1": "123 Candy Lane",
    "address_line_2": "",
    "locality": "Smithfield",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "RI",
    "postal_code": "02917",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "capabilities": [
    "CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING"
  ]
},
{
  "id": "4FHNAN1WXXXXX",
  "name": "MyCompany2",
  "address": {
    "address_line_1": "567 Smith Street",
    "address_line_2": "",
    "locality": "Greenville",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "RI",
    "postal_code": "02828-2910",
    "country": "US"
  },
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "capabilities": [
    "CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING"
  ]
 }
 ]
 }
```

I modified the returned IDs a bit in the above example.

Next I make a call to charge a card to this uri:

```
https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/FPVPFZ4DXXXXX/transactions
```

With this body:

```
{  
"note":"",
"idempotency_key":"azsxdcfvrtrewsdf",
"location_id":"FPVPFZ4DXXXXX",
"shipping_address":{  
  "address_line_1":"123 My Street",
  "address_line_2":null,
  "locality":"Greenville",
  "administrative_district_level_1":"RI",
  "postal_code":"02828",
  "country":"US"
},
"billing_address":{  
  "address_line_1":"123 My Street",
  "address_line_2":null,
  "locality":"Greenville",
  "administrative_district_level_1":"RI",
  "postal_code":"02828",
  "country":"US"
},
"card_nonce":"CBASEPPW7fjdUHe-3jP6ZZ4kvE0gAQ",
"reference_id":"RT-12345678",
"amount_money":{  
  "amount":12500,
  "currency":"USD"
},
"delay_capture":true,
"buyer_email_address":"jim@xxxxxxxxxx.net",
"customer_id":"JIM"
}
```

And I get this response:

```
{
"errors": [
{
  "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
  "code": "NOT_FOUND",
  "detail": "This merchant does not have a location with the ID    `FPVPFZ4DXXXXX`.",
  "field": "location_id"
}
]
}
```

So the location ID matches exactly the ID returned by the locations endpoint.

Can someone familiar with this API help me out?  Square's docs and support is sadly lacking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is that you have tried to use your sandbox credentials (`sandbox-sq0idp-defoUOlu...`) to charge against your production location `FPVPFZXXXXX`. If you call `ListLocations` with your sandbox credentials, you should get a different location that you can then do sandbox charges with.

Comment: Thanks @tristansokol but I tried that. Then I do that, I get different locations and when I try to use one, I got forbidden and an error that says I don't have access to that location.

Comment: Then I think you tried to use your personal access token with a sandbox location. Try location `CBASEHHNorL75Tj...` with `sandbox-sq0atb-R6...` and any errors you get should be related the body of your request.

Comment: Thanks @tristansokol I'm willing to try, but the comment editor truncated the location key and sandbox token you posted. Could you perhaps edit your answer and add them there?  Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, I did that truncation so that your credentials aren't posted online (even if they are sandbox). You can find that sandbox token on the [Square Developer Portal](https://connect.squareup.com/apps/sq0idp-defoUOluf8eqmTqIWxHeYw) and the location by calling list locations with that access code.

Comment: Okay I tried that again and this time I got a valid response, thank you. I am sure that when I tried it initially I got "forbidden" but perhaps it was because the location added was new or the account is new. Anyhow it's working now, thank you.